# How to search for a particular value in grok when logs has different patterns

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, filebeat, grok

need to create a new field status_code with value-successful by using ingest pipeline when status inside message field has 200 and when status inside message field is 502,404,402 it muse create status_code with value failed.

Figured out how to create the fields but was unable to pick the exact value of status from the logs.
Sample logs:

{action:show,count:208,duration:6.38ms,status:200}

How do I write a grok pattern to pick status value alone from these logs? 200 has different logs compared to 404. Hence unable to define a common pattern(each 404 has different log structure as well)

Comment: Could you please add logs example for different status code ?

Comment: As I understood from your sample log, your logs are in json format. in this case you should have the field status already there with the status code. If this is the case, you could just add an if statement in the filter, and add a field with the appropriate value (mutate). please let me know if understood it correctly.

Comment: Hi Luka, I do not have any field called status in my document.

Comment: Hi Sourav, I have different types of logs for error. Some are json some are string . Some have different types of timestamps as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to resolve this issue is to write a grok pattern for different log formats. The set processor in ingest node pipeline could be used to add a new field and in the condition of the set processor, I wrote a condtion to check if the status has value 200 or 404 then added a new field called app_statuscode.

Hence if it has 200 status in the message app_statuscode will be success and if it's 404 or 502 or 403 it will be having value failed.

Grok pattern used : %{GREEDYDATA:temp1},status:%{NUMBER:statucode}%{GREEDYDATA:temp2}

This is a sample one I had used it scrapes off value present in status.Need to make the pattern more specific and do not use Greedy data as it picks anything present in the log.

```
ctx['app_statuscode']=="200"
```

Used this condition in set processor to check if status has value 200 or not.

There will be a need to have 2 set processors one for successful one other for failed
status code.

```
ctx['app_statuscode']=="404"||ctx['app_statuscode']=="502"
```